# Maintain cookies upon exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a screen which has grid on it. The grid has one column as hyperlinks. Hyperlink opens a document in a new window.Whenever there is exception while loading the doc in new window, I need to display the exception and the parent screen should continue to work. Currently when the exception occurs while loading the doc in new window and if I close the window the cookies get cleared and hence the parent screen also dies out.
I need to keep parent alive even after closing the new window.
I am using Asp.net mvc3.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is not clear. Cookies are sent with every request and can't be reset on their own (they can expire though). Please add more details to the question so we can help you.

Comment: The problem is when the child window is closed (in case exception occurs while loading the doc) and I navigate to the parent screen(grid and try to filter the grid data) the cookies are not available and hence the parent window expires. The code checks the cookies prior to load the screen. While debugging I see that the cookie value is reset.

Comment: I have one parent page with links. Clicking on a link opens a child page in new window.
When exception occurs while loading child, error is shown on child as'pls try again'. Now if I close the child and go back to the parent page to access other functionality, it seems, that the cookie is reset...but if I do not close the child,where exception occurred,the cookie has val n parent page works fine

Thus it seems that closing the browser window(child) resets the cookie..I need a way out to maintain the cookie value. as it is reqd for the parent to work fine.

Hope I am clear